# Linux headers for ubuntu docker image 18.04

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu

I am trying to install linux header for my ubuntu 18.04 docker image (ubuntu:18.04). Usually I will do `sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)` in my VM to get the current linux header packages.

But the docker image return the following when I run uname -r

```
root@0c4e24cca819:/# uname -r
4.19.76-linuxkit
```

Just wonder which linux header image I should use for ubuntu:18.04 docker image?

Comment: Why do you need the kernel headers here?  The kernel is not isolated between containers, and container processes are usually forbidden from installing custom modules (which would affect other containers and potentially compromise the host).

Answer (score 1):

Docker by definition runs your current kernel. If you are on a machine whose kernel has not been packaged for Ubuntu then there is no package you can install to get its headers.

Looks like you're on a Mac, so definitely that is the case here. Perhaps you could ask the Docker for Mac maintainers to provide headers for some popular platforms for their kernel, but I suspect they don't want to take on that responsibility.

As a workaround, maybe run Docker inside Linux on e.g. Virtualbox.